# MVC and django fundamentals

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

Pretty new to this scene and trying to find some documentation to adopt best practices.  We're building a fairly large content site which will consist of various media catalogs and I'm trying to find some comparable data / architectural models so that we can get a better idea of the approach we should use using a framework we've never made use of before.   Any insight / help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 16):

"data / architectural models so that we can get a better idea of the approach we should use using a framework we've never made use of before"

Django imposes best practices on you.  You don't have a lot of choices and can't make a lot of mistakes.

MVC (while a noble aspiration) is implemented as follows:

- Data is defined in "models.py" files using the Django ORM models.
- urls.py file maps URL to view function.  Pick your URL's wisely.
- View function does all processing, making use of models and methods in models
- Presentation (via HTML templates) invoked by View function.  Essentially no processing can be done in presentation, just lightweight iteration and decision-making

The model is defined for you.  Just stick to what Django does naturally and you'll be happy.

Architecturally, you usually have a stack like this.

- Apache does two things.

  - serves static content directly and immediately
  - hands dynamic URL to Django (via mod_python, mod_wsgi or mod_fastcgi).  Django apps map URL to view functions (which access to database (via ORM/model) and display via templates.
- Database used by Django view functions.

The architecture is well-defined for you.  Just stick to what Django does naturally and you'll be happy.

Feel free to read the [Django documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/).  It's excellent; perhaps the best there is.

Comment: If you're concerned about performance or memory usage, it's often better to have a separate lightweight webserver (such as Nginx) for serving static content, rather than using Apache for both (though you can get similar effect if you use mod_wsgi in daemon mode and Apache worker MPM).

Comment: @Carl Meyer: or lighttpd for serving static content.

Answer (score 5):

first, forget all MVC mantra.  it's important to have a good layered structure, but MVC (as defined originally) isn't one, it was a **modular** structure, where each **GUI** module is split in these tree submodules.  nothing to use on the web here.

in web development, it really pays to have a layered structure, where the most important layer is the storage/modelling one, which came to be called *model layer*.  on top of that, you need a few other layers but they're really not anything like views and controllers in the GUI world.

the Django layers are roughly:

- storage/modelling: models.py, obviously.  try to put most of the 'working' concepts there.  all the relationships, all the operations should be implemented here.
- dispatching: mostly in urls.py.  here you turn your URL scheme into code paths.  think of it like a big switch() statement.  try hard to have readable URLs, which map into user intentions.  it will help a lot to add new functionality, or new ways to do the same things (like an AJAX UI later).
- gathering: mostly the view functions, both yours and the prebuilt generic views.  here you simply gather all the from the models to satisfy a user request.  in surprisingly many cases, it just have to pick a single model instance, and everything else can be retrieved from relationships.  for these URLs, a generic view is enough.
- presentation: the templates.  if the view gives you the data you need, it's simple enough to turn it into a webpage.  it's here where you'll thank that the model classes have good accessors to get any kind of relevant data from any given instance.

Answer (score 1):

To understand django fundementals and the django take on MVC, consult the following:
http://www.djangobook.com/

As a starting point to getting your hands dirty  with ...
"...trying to find some comparable data / architectural models"

Here is a quick and dirty way to reverse engineer a database to get a models.py file,
which you can then inspect to see how django would handle it.

1.) get an er diagram that closely matches your target. For example something like this
    http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/product_catalogs/index.htm

2.) create an sql script from the er diagram and create the database, 
    I suggest Postgre, as some MySQL
    table type will not have forgien key constraints, but in a pinch MySQL or SQLITE
    will do

3.) create and configure a django app to use that database. Then run:
     python manage.py inspectdb

This will at least give you a models.py file which you can read to see how django attempts
to model it.

Note that the inspect command is intended to be a shortcut for dealing with legacy
database when developing in django, and as such is not perfect. Be sure to read the
following before attempting this:
 http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#ref-django-admin