# Reading code of real production projects. How to find?

Tags: model-view-controller, oop, open-source, domain-driven-design

I really like the idea of reading others people code to improve your design skills. Open source can help here a lot.

This can teach you basic OO principles. But **I'm not writing frameworks**, **I'm writing code for real customers** with quite complicated domain logic.

There are lots of manuals of different MVC frameworks(like [Create a blog with Ruby on rails in 15 minutes](http://weblog.rubyonrails.com/2008/11/27/new-15-minute-blog-video-on-rails-2-2)). But hey it is difficult to mess with small pet project.

How can I get a possibility of reading real production code dealing with complicated business domain logic?

I'm interested in any MVC frameworks(any languages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ASP.NET quickly](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/184719754X) offers a pretty comprehensive case study of an MVC implementation at the end of the book.

Comment: That book is very poor compared to the book pro ASP.NET MVC Framework by Steven Sanderson

Comment: I like the PRO series too, but didn't have the time so I gave that one a try.

Comment: Thanks, Yura! I haven't worked with ASP.NET before but I think that it doesn't matter :) Will read this one.

Comment: @Yukiy- I read both and preferred the pro one by far

Answer (score 1):

Django is both object oriented and MVC based framework written in Python. The [Chapter 5: Models](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter05/) of the free Django book explains the MVC pattern as applied to Django.

Also look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364015/mvc-and-django-fundamentals).